# Settlement of currency options

Tags: options

wanted to understand the market action done to settle a call option.

Let's say I entered into a export seagull for eurusd and on the date of expiry my sell call gets exercised. Assuming that my sell call was at 1.1000 and spot on expiry is 1.1200.

Since my sell call has been exercised, what's the market action that I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you sold the call on the EUR with a strike of USD 1.10, and you did not have the EUR on hand, you would have to buy EUR at market to deliver to the long call holder.    You would buy EUR at USD 1.12 and deliver those EUR to the call holder that exercised.  You would receive USD 1.10 on exercise so you would lose USD 0.02 per EUR on the exercise.  Of course this would be offset by the premiums you might have received on your structure.